# What is the right unsalvageable category for "Wall of Code" questions that need a Minimum, Reproducible, Complete example?

Tags: discussion, triage, minimal-reproducible-example

During Triage reviews, I'm having difficulty categorizing questions that are generally good, but they have posted their entire script, group of files, etc.

- These are questions where the user needs to be redirected to the help page on how to provide a good

  - [Minimum, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
- A further explanation of why "Wall of Code" questions deserve a downvote can be found here:

  - [I downvoted because... a wall of code isn't helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/)

I believe these are "unsalvageable", because the author is responsible for doing the work required to create a "Minimum, Complete, Reproducible" example so his question is clear in the minimum amount of space, which is good for everyone involved (and, incidentally, he will often solve his own problem in the process).

In addition, many posts tangentially fit this category because they are not **reproducible** - often because they are missing import statements, header file info, support files, or other configuration settings needed to recreate the error.

i.e. These should not be marked as "requires editing", because it's not the community's job to parse through questions and figure out how to minimize the code. In many cases this can't be done due to reproducibility problems anyway.

### Which unsalvagable category to choose?

In trying to choose a flag for these questions, I'm having difficulty choosing the right category. They don't seem to fit - at least the descriptions don't. Here are the options that might fit:

- Unsalvagable

  - needs improvement (The question needs updates from the author in order to be answered well...)

    1. Needs details or clarity

       - This question should include more details and clarify the problem.
    2. Needs more focus

       - This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.
    3. Opinion-based

       - This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

None of these seem to fit exactly. The question needs refinement, and actually some development effort to narrow the focus and create a set of code that someone else could actually run on their system easily to reproduce the issue, while focusing it down to the one specific error that this question needs to address. It may be missing a few pieces to be reproducible.

I think the "Needs Details or Clarity" category fits the best, but it's often that the problem is clear and there are enough details to answer it, just that the question needs to be refined and focused. But if you look at the description for "Needs more focus", it doesn't seem to fit - i.e. there aren't really multiple questions, it's more that there is extra, unnecessary code that is hiding the key issue.

### Is the user getting the right response?

Another key concern here is that, especially for new users, that the response they get clarifies for them that they need to focus their code and go through the (sometimes) hard work of creating the minimum code that still causes the error, while making sure they also include enough context and scaffolding code to make it reproducible.

I can comment on the question directly with a link to that information, but that takes time and slows down my ability (and desire) to run through some triage reviews.

In addition, I'm not sure I'm marking these specific types of questions correctly.

---

### Questions

1. Which category should be choosen in the current system for "Wall of code" questions?
2. Should the category descriptions be updated to clarify for reviewers which one to pick in this case?
3. Or - Should a new category be added specific to this type of problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason you're looking for is: **A community-specific reason > Needs debugging details**

The description for this is (emphasis added):

> The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and ***the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem***.

If the person asking the question has provided a wall of 500 lines of code, that's almost never "the *shortest code necessary* reproduce the problem." *Especially* if they're not clear exactly where to look.

**A small caveat about walls of code**: I've seen questions with a lot of code that *also* had a description of *exactly* what the problem was, including enough specifics that a bit of Ctrl+F finds it in the code. Often, in those cases, the rest of the code is helpful context.  But if they don't give you enough to do that, then "Needs debugging details" is the appropriate close reason.

Comment: Okay, so "debugging details" means the poster needs to provide more details tried so far in debugging, and/or to allow other users to debug further by getting them a quickly as possible to where the user got "stuck" in the debugging process? That makes sense.

Comment: Exactly.  It's the details required to debug, whether that's things already tried that answerers don't need to try, or the information needed to reproduce the situation locally to try to debug it.

Comment: Another problem I sometimes see is that they've tried to isolate the problem and haven't been able to do so, so the minimum repro is indeed a wall of code.

Answer (score 1):

#### *"Needs debugging details"* is what I usually choose for questions with a *Wall of code*.

The explanation can easily be found in the phrase *"Needs debugging details"*:

Questions with a *Wall of code* tend have a lot of unnecessary code, or in other words, a lot of unnecessary **details**. Unnecessary things need to be removed, or in other words, **debugged**, to **keep our site as clean as possible**.

On the heading, I say *usually* because there *are* times when such questions are obvious duplicates, needs more focus, etc.